# Who is the voice actor for Vlad in Magicka?

Tags: magicka, magicka-2

What is the name of the actor who narrates the story and voices the non-vampire character [Vlad](http://magicka.wikia.com/wiki/Vlad) in the Magicka series?

A web search doesn't mention the voice actors of the game at all, nor are the creators listed in Wikia or Magickapedia. I realize they may be named in the games' credits roll, but I don't have either one installed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [official Magicka manual](https://store.steampowered.com/manual/42910) lists Todd Benzin as Vlad on page 16.

Comment: This is the first time I realize that this game had a manual. (And that it is available on Steam.)

Comment: What's interesting is that the second game doesn't seem to have one. But he is still listed in the credits under `Breslin Studios` section. Also, there was an `Executive Commitee of Humor` section somewhere there as well.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this answer](https://www.reddit.com/r/IAmA/comments/sry7j/i_am_we_are_the_guys_that_madepublished_magicka/c4gh1t5) from [a reddit AMA](https://www.reddit.com/r/IAmA/comments/sry7j/i_am_we_are_the_guys_that_madepublished_magicka/), it's possible that the voice actor was actually Magicka's sound designer, **Andreas Almström**

[image: reddit quote]

Comment: This is a good find, but it is unclear to me whether the verb "did" is intended to mean that he recorded his own self or whether he simply brought in some voice actors and then did whatever a sound producer normally does.